# Multiple Segue from Table View Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a table view with different information the user can update. One of them is "pilot information". When the user clicks on this row they are taking to another view controller where they fill out information on the pilot. (name phone number etc)
They can then hit save or cancel both of which return them to the previous table view controller. What I want to do is have the user be able to click on pilot information again, and view the data they just entered and edit it if they choose. My solution to this was to add another segue and give it a unique identifier using the following code. (pilot is the name of the entity in my core data model, updatepilot is the name I gave the segue.)

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"UpdatePilot"]) {
        NSManagedObject *selectedPilot = [self.pilots objectAtIndex:[[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow] row]];
        PilotViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        destViewController.pilot = selectedPilot;
    }
}
```

!http://tinypic.com/r/2ihbera/8

However, I get the error use of undeclared identifier 'destviewcontroller" did you mean UIViewController? Is there something I'm not seeing here? any help would be appreciated!

```
#import "PilotViewController.h"

@interface PilotViewController ()

@end

@implementation PilotViewController
- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext {
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = nil;
    id delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    if ([delegate performSelector:@selector(managedObjectContext)]) {
        context = [delegate managedObjectContext];
    }
    return context;
}

@synthesize pilot;


- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {

        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    if (self.pilot) {
        [self.nameField setText:[self.pilot valueForKey:@"pilotName"]];
        [self.emailField setText:[self.pilot valueForKey:@"pilotEmail"]];
        [self.phoneField setText:[self.pilot valueForKey:@"pilotPhone"]];
        [self.insuranceField setText:[self.pilot valueForKey:@"pilotInsurance"]];



    }
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

//Code created for cancel and save buttons
- (IBAction)cancel:(id)sender {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (IBAction)save:(id)sender {

    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

    if (self.pilot) {
        // Update existing Pilot
        [self.pilot setValue:self.nameField.text forKey:@"pilotName"];
        [self.pilot setValue:self.phoneField.text forKey:@"pilotPhone"];
        [self.pilot setValue:self.insuranceField.text forKey:@"pilotInsurance"];
        [self.pilot setValue:self.emailField.text forKey:@"pilotEmail"];

    } else {
        // Create a new pilot
        NSManagedObject *newPilot = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Pilot" inManagedObjectContext:context];
        [newPilot setValue:self.nameField.text forKey:@"pilotName"];
        [newPilot setValue:self.phoneField.text forKey:@"pilotPhone"];
        [newPilot setValue:self.insuranceField.text forKey:@"pilotInsurance"];
         [newPilot setValue:self.emailField.text forKey:@"pilotEmail"];
    }

    NSError *error = nil;
    // Save the object to persistent store
    if (![context save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Can't Save! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
    }

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
@end
```

Comment: Did you set identifier in storyboard ? please check once because many makes mistakes just forgetting

Comment: by that do you mean the segue? or the view controller?

Comment: yes i mean segue identifer

Comment: yes segue identifier is set to UpdatePilot

Comment: Can you please paste the error exactly as it is reported? Because `destviewcontroller` (all lowercase) is nowhere to be found on your snippet... Also please provide some info on how you `#import` the `PilotViewController`

Comment: Error was solved by casting and importing PilotViewController.h however while I don't receive any errors, if I fill out the form and click save and click on it again I don't see the previous information. Any suggestions on to what might be the issue>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try casting the `segue.destinationViewController` (which is type `id`) to PilotViewController.

```
PilotViewController *destViewController = (PilotViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
```

In previous versions of Xcode I believe I saw this as a warning; your build settings may be set to treat all warnings as errors.

Comment: I'm fairly new to ios development and am not sure what casting means or how to accomplish this, can you provide me some information on how to do that?

Comment: Thanks for the code snippet, making those changes, worked! However while I no longer get any error, upon clicking on the pilot information, adding information and returning I don't see any of the previous data

Comment: Double-check your save action method within the PilotViewController to be sure you're setting (or have already set) the relevant properties on the NSManagedObject for the pilot (eg, [pilot setValue:@"Maverick" forKey:@"name"], if the user typed Maverick into the Name field). Also make sure you're doing the reverse when the PilotViewController loads (pre-populate the Name field with [self.pilot valueForKey:@"name"]) so that the current values show up when that view loads.

Comment: Tried both those things, I've edited my post to include PilotViewController.m as well